# EJB + Hibernate + REST client LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, ejb, lazy-initialization

My REST client was working until I added Hibernate for the persistence then whenever I make a request I obtain an Error 500 with this message:

> Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: uo.sdi.dto.User.tasks, could not initialize proxy - no Session.

I've been reading lots of answers about this topic but none of them happen on this scenario. The error raises when I call the "FindLoggableUser" method in order to check whether a user can be logged on or not.

**FindLoggableUser**

```
User user = Factories.persistence.getUserDao().findByLoginAndPassword(login, password);
```

**FindByLoginAndPassword**

```
User res = Jpa.getManager()
              .createQuery(Jdbc.getSqlQuery("USER_FIND_BY_LOGIN_AND_PASSWORD")
              ,User.class).setParameter(1, login).setParameter(2, password)
              .getSingleResult();
return res;
```

**Jpa.java**

```
public class Jpa {

    private static ThreadLocal<EntityManager> emThread = 
        new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    public static EntityManager getManager() {
        EntityManager entityManager = emThread.get();
        if (entityManager == null) {
            entityManager = jndiFind("java:/GtdJpaEntityManager");
            emThread.set(entityManager);
        }
        return entityManager;
    }

    private static EntityManager jndiFind(String name) {
        Context ctx;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            return (EntityManager) ctx.lookup(name);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And my user class

**User.java**

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String login;
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;
private String password;
private Boolean isAdmin = false;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private UserStatus status = UserStatus.ENABLED;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();
```

These are the attributes of my class and the error raises when tryin to access the `tasks` collection:

```
public Set<Task> getTasks(){
    return new HashSet<Task>(tasks);
}
```

I've tried setting the initialization as eager but it also fails. Regarding other questions, some people recommended to control the session manually in order to get an approach to the session per request pattern, but I've also read that it is not possible to control the session when using an EntityManager.

Do you have any solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats inside Jpa.getManager().. and is the DAO method transactional

Comment: @MaciejKowalski have just updated the information, and not, is not transactional. I have a doubt with that annotation, if I'd use it, should I declare each method with that annotation or is it enough to declare the class as transactional?

Comment: I had this problem. How did you resolve @SergioMD15?

Answer (score 0):

You must configure [lazy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties) for collections

In your case is for tasks.

Comment: I suppose the configuration on your answer is the same as including the `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` declaration inside OneToMany annotations. Unluckily I've already tried that before and it didn't worked for me.